# How to reduce the number of nodes with AWS OpenSearch Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

You can't do the 'normal' way of reducing nodes because you cannot update cluster settings. So how does one reduce the number of nodes?

Answer (score 1):

AWS has limitation to reduce the number of nodes. You can only change instance type if needed. To reduce the number of nodes or storage, create a new cluster with required configuration and reindex the data from old cluster to new one.

Comment: Good lord! That's a bit of an...oversight! Isn't it? Could I also restore from a snapshot into a new cluster?

Comment: yes, definitely you can take snapshot of existing cluster and restore on new one.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to take a snapshot on OpenSearch!